# CSS select first 4 elements that do not have class x

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of elements and i want to select the first 4 elements not counting the first one which might have the class **.current**.

I can not change the HTML and i can only use CSS.

```
<span class="example-1">
    <div class="item current">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</span>

<span class="example-2">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</span>
```

In example 1 i want only item 2, 3, 4 and 5 to be visible.
And in example 2 i want only items 1, 2, 3 and 4 to be visible.

What i'm trying is this:

```
span {
  display: none;
}
span:not(.current):nth-child(-n+4){
  display: initial;
}
```

But what happens now, is that when the item **.current** is present, it will only show the next 3 items (2, 3 and 4)

Does anyone know how i can select the next 4 items after current?

Comment: `:nth-child` does not care about any other selectors you try to apply at the same time. The first four childs are always the first four childs, nothing changes that.

Comment: I figured that out. But there must be a way to select those other four items right?

Comment: .example-1 div{
  display:none;
}
.example-1 div:not(.current){
  display:block;
}
.example-1 div:last-child{
  display: none;
}

Comment: Thanks Jacob but it is possible to be more rows then that. So simply hiding the last one won't cut it. @Jacob

Comment: Maybe you can find some inspiration for something you can combine with your specific requirement here, https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/

Comment: Pure CSS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/x3vd841k/